# SQL Server 2012 - Function returns NULL when executed by a SQL user but not Windows user/group

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, authentication

I'm executing a scalar-valued function under Programmability -> Functions -> Scalar-valued Functions.

```
SELECT dbo.fn_EndOfThisYear(GetDate())
```

When logged in as a user part of a Windows group, this returns '2015-01-01 05:00:00.000'

When logged in as a SQL user, the same statement returns NULL.

Can anyone explain why and what I need to change?

Comment: Might you share the function code with us?

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction. I did not create these functions, so after more digging, I realized it's dependent on a UTC to local time conversion function which finds the current user's guid. The SQL user account has no guid and therefore returns NULL.

Answer (score 1):

The function's definition was dependent on another function which finds the user's guid and converts UTC to local time. The SQL user account has no guid and therefore was returning NULL.